Xamarin Android to .NET 8 Upgrade: ZXing.Net.Mobile QR Code Scanning Issue
I've recently upgraded my Xamarin Android project to .NET 8 (net8-android). My project still uses MainActivity and has not yet been upgraded to MAUI. While most of the features work fine, the QR code scanning feature is failing. I'm using ZXing.Net.Mobile for QR code scanning, and it seems to be incompatible with net8-android.
Has anyone encountered this issue or can suggest a solution for making ZXing.Net.Mobile work with .NET 8 for Android? Alternatively, can anyone recommend a different QR code scanning library that is compatible with .NET 8 for Android?

I didn't know you could "upgrade to .NET 8" other than upgrading to MAUI.  That said, I guess I'm not surprised that you have an incompatibility.
